# How can I add a constant row to an SQL result set?

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL but basically I am trying to get customer data and everything works except I want to add an email address to the final results every time this is causing the problems.

This for a volusion based website.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here is my code

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Orders.ShipFirstName, 
    Customers.EmailAddress
FROM 
    Orders
JOIN 
    Customers ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
WHERE
    Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'
    AND Orders.ShipDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 20, GETDATE())
    AND Orders.ShipDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())

UNION ALL

INSERT INTO Customers (EmailAddress)
VALUES ('Testemail@gmail.com');
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID desc
```

what I am trying to do is this, everytime I run this, add my email address at the end, because we send out order updates to all the people whose information is exported, and I want to make sure that I get a copy of that email, without needing to CC my self on each email.

I don't actually want to add anything to the real table, just to my results

For example right now when I run this I get this result

```
3104    10/9/2014 12:54:00 PM   Jeanine jrgtnce@yahoo.com
3065    10/6/2014 1:01:00 PM    Annamarie   the.annamarie@gmail.com

But I want this

3104    10/9/2014 12:54:00 PM   Jeanine jrgtnce@yahoo.com
3065    10/6/2014 1:01:00 PM    Annamarie   te.annrie@gmail.com
null        nulll               null           testemail@gmail.com
```

testemail@gmail.com will be changed to my personal email

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?!?!?! Combine a `SELECT` and an `INSERT` into a single query? What's that all about?!?!? **Either** you're **selecting** data - then you have multiple `SELECT` in your `UNION` - or you are **inserting** data - but you cannot mix those two, really ....

Comment: I apologize I didn't make this clear I want to run a select, but in  my exported values I wanted to add my own email address so each time I sent an email to this list I got an email as well

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you don't really want to add the same data to `Customers` every time you run the query, but just add a synthesized record to the results:

```
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Orders.ShipFirstName, 
    Customers.EmailAddress
FROM 
    Orders
JOIN 
    Customers ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
WHERE
    Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'
    AND Orders.ShipDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 20, GETDATE())
    AND Orders.ShipDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Testemail@gmail.com'
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to do I believe but I ran it got this error SQL Error: A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: I don't see you assigning anything to a variable - is that somewhere else in your query?

Comment: I updated above with an example of what I am looking to get, let me know if I am missing something here...thank so much for the help

Comment: The query I posted should produce that - again, I don't see any variables so I can't say why you're getting that error.

Comment: Okay I don't know either there is nothing more to my code then what I showed here...it could be a problem with Volusion (my shopping cart)

Comment: I tested the above on a Volusion store and it works exactly as stated, appending the email to the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO #TempCustomerTable
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Orders.ShipFirstName, 
    Customers.EmailAddress
FROM 
    Orders
JOIN 
    Customers ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
WHERE
    Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'
    AND Orders.ShipDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 20, GETDATE())
    AND Orders.ShipDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID desc


-- If you are trying to update all users  email address

UPDATE #TempCustomerTable
SET EmailAddress = 'Testemail@gmail.com'

-- If you are trying to insert new record with just email assuming no null constraints
INSERT INTO #TempCustomerTable
VALUES(NULL, NULL,NULL, 'Testemail@gmail.com')

or 


-- If you are trying to update all users  email address
SELECT 
    Orders.OrderID,
    Orders.OrderDate,
    Orders.ShipFirstName, 
    'Testemail@gmail.com' AS EmailAddress
FROM 
    Orders
JOIN 
    Customers ON customers.customerid = orders.customerid
WHERE
    Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped'
    AND Orders.ShipDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 20, GETDATE())
    AND Orders.ShipDate <= DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID desc
```

Comment: (just curious) Wouldn't `Orders.ShipDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 20, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETDATE())` be cleaner and/or execute faster?

Comment: I did not look at the users query. I pretty much regurgitated the query with my answer.

Comment: Thanks I am just trying to set a new record I ran it and got this error... There is an error in your SQL syntax. Please correct the error listed below.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.

Comment: When you do an insert into a a temp table the temp table must be created. If you dont want to precreate it then you can select * into #NewTempTable From ( the select statement ) a